# Существует ли бесплатный Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-basic

Существует ли бесплатный Visual Basic, желательно 2008, или любой другой, если он по принципу работы совпадает с 2008-м?
Нужен для работы на Windows 8.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А зачем взломанная, если есть свободная и бесплатная?
http://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/products/visual-studio-community-vs или http://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Comment: спасибо. я видел, но мне казалось, что она будет кардинально отличаться от Basic в Visual Studio 2008 версии. нет?

Comment: А чему там сильно отличаться? Дизайном немного, новыми функциями. Но если хочется сильно близкое к 2008, то можно попробовать качнуть [2010 студию экспресс версии](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs).

Answer (score 0):

Качаешь Visual Basic 2010 Express...регистрируешься и тебе на почту присылают
код активации и вуаля...пользуйся вечно...я сижу на windows 10...работает
нормально...очень удобное средство разработки для домашних поделок